# Excel javascript custom functions deployement

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

Now that I built [my first Excel javascript custom function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows)
I want to deploy it so users can add it in their sheets, but didn't find any useful infos. My questions:

- What to deploy exactly? (manifest, js files...)
- Where to deploy? Is a shared folder enought?
- Do I need NodeJs in client machines?

Comment: Deploy custom function could be similar to deploy an Office Add-in, here's the docs may help you:
[Custom Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview), 
[Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish), 
You need to publish your website(js) to a server, and the put the server website in the manifest, and share the manifest to others.
For internal share, you could use [ScriptLab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/)

Answer (score 1):

The over view introduction on how to deploy custom function could be find [Custom function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview). Custom Function deployment is similar to an Office Add-in and change in manifest is needed.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit, I found this section, and will update my answer when I've successfully deployed to production.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish?view=excel-js-preview

Deployment documentation is hard to find.  The dist folder contains the files for a Production environment.  Look for the Resources node in your manifest.xml.  Here is one referring to files in localhost.  These are in the dist folder.  You'll want to upload the contents of the dist folder to a server file share, or S3 bucket, after all of your changes have been built.

```
<Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/public/functions.js"/>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/public/functions.json"/>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Functions.Namespace" DefaultValue="FinTools_Azure"/>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Quantitative Finance SaaS"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="FinTools_Azure has successfully loaded"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
</Resources>
```

Then update all of those links, and anywhere else in manifest.xml that refers to localhost